# Submit to itself don't work

Tags: php, plugin-development, redirect, actions

Currently I am creating site wordpress.lockout.lt. One functionality is developed by me; it works fine with the default theme. Currently I am using a different one. And as well this theme requires lot of different plugins. Now, when inserting my plugin shortcode it doesn't redirect request to itself. Instead I receive a message, that "Page is not found". Form code is enclosed below. First I thought that it's related with action; I tried a lot of different things to set action properly but it didn't help me:

```
    $formtxt .= '<form  style="width: 800px;" name="time_booking"  action="#" onsubmit="return validateCalendarForm();" method = "POST">';
    $formtxt .= '<div class="w3-row-padding" align = "center"  width="800 px">';
    $formtxt .='<table style = "text-align: center;" id = "timeslotstable" width="800 px" border="1">';
    $formtxt .='<caption>'.$table_name.'</caption>';

          $formtxt .='<tr>';

          $formtxt .='<tr>';  // time value begin
          $formtxt .='<th width="100 px"></th>'; // time value end
          for ($j = 0; $j < 7; $j++) {      

                   $formtxt .='<th width="100 px" >'.date_format($actual_date,"Y-m-d").'</th>';
                   date_add($actual_date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 days"));
           }

         $formtxt .='</tr>';



    for ($i = 0; $i < $periods_count; $i++) {      

         $actual_date= clone $monday;
         $formtxt .='<tr>';  // time value begin

                  $visit_time = $start_time  + $i*$period_len;
                  $formtxt .='<td>'.gmdate("H:i", $visit_time).'</td>'; // time value end


                 for ($j = 0; $j < 7; $j++) {                    

                             $notexist = 0;
                             foreach ($activereservationslist as $result) {

                                    if ($result->visit_time ==  date_format($actual_date,"Y-m-d").' '.gmdate("H:i", $visit_time) ) {
                                          $notexist = 1;      
                                    }
                             } 


                             if ($notexist == 1 or date_format($actual_date,"Y-m-d") <= date("Y-m-d") ){                                
                                       $formtxt .='<td  bgcolor = "red" align ="center" >';                                 
                             } else {
                                       $formtxt .='<td style="text-align:center;" bgcolor = "green" >';                                 
                                       $formtxt .='<input  style="w3-radio" type="radio"  name="time_selection" id="time_selection" value="'.date_format($actual_date,"Y-m-d").' '.gmdate("H:i", $visit_time).'">';
                             }


                            date_add($actual_date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 days"));
                   }

         $formtxt .='</tr>';

    }
    $formtxt .='</table>';
               $formtxt .='<div id="errftimeselection"></div>';

                $formtxt .='<div class="w3-row-padding" width="800 px">';   

                if ($page >1 ) {                    
                  $formtxt .='<input class="button button-xsmall button-line-dark" type="submit" align ="left" name= "previousweek" id= "previousweek" value="Buvusi Savaite" onclick="previousweekfocus()">'; 
                }


                if ($page <13 ) {                                        
                  $formtxt .='<input class="button button-xsmall button-line-dark" type="submit" align ="right" name= "nextweek" id= "nextweek" value="Sekanti Savaite" onclick="nextweekfocus()"> <br>';
                }



                $formtxt .='</div>';   
                $formtxt .='<div class="w3-row-padding">';  
                $formtxt .='<div class="w3-half">';    
                $formtxt .='<p>';
                $formtxt .='<label for= "nameval">Vardas Pavardė</label>';
                $formtxt .='<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" name="nameval" id="nameval" type="text" onblur="validateName()"><div id="errfname"></div></p>';
                $formtxt .='<p>';
                $formtxt .='<p>';
                $formtxt .='<label for="email">Email</label>';
                $formtxt .='<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="email"  name="email" id="email" onblur="validateEmail()"/><div id="errfemail"></div>';                        
                $formtxt .='<p>';
                $formtxt .='<p>';
                $formtxt .='<label for="phone_number" >Mob. tel.</label>';
                $formtxt .='<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" id="phone_number" name="phone_number"  placeholder = "8 XXX XXXXX" type="text" onblur  = "validatePhone()"/><div id="errfphonenumber"></div>';                        
                $formtxt .='<p>';
                $formtxt .='<input type="hidden" name="room"  value="'.$room.'"/>';
                $formtxt .='<input type="hidden" name="activepage"  value="'.$page.'"/>';
                $formtxt .=' <label for= "payment_type">Apmokėjimo būdas </label>';
                $formtxt .=' <select class="w3-select w3-border" name = "payment_type" id = "payment_type" onChange="paymtypeselector(this)">';
                $formtxt .='  <option value="local">Vietoje</option>';
                $formtxt .='  <option value="ebank">Pavedimu</option>';
                $formtxt .='  <option value="coupon">Kuponas</option>';
                $formtxt .='  </select>';   
                $formtxt .='<p>';
            $formtxt .='<label id ="couponidtxt" for = "couponid">   Kupono nr. </label>';
                $formtxt .='<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="couponid" id = "couponid" name="couponid" /><div id="errfcouponid"></div>';     
                $formtxt .='</div>';
                $formtxt .='<div class="w3-half">';
                $formtxt .='<label><font color="blue">    </font></label>';                        
                $formtxt .='<p>';
                $formtxt .='<p></p>';
                $formtxt .='<label><font color="blue"> Jei reikalinga Sąskaita Faktūra: </font></label>';     
                $formtxt .='<p></p>';
                $formtxt .='<p>';
                $formtxt .='<label for="company_id">Įmonės pavadinimas</label>'; 
                $formtxt .='<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" name="company_name" id="company_name" type="text" >';      
                $formtxt .='<p>';
                $formtxt .='<label for="company_id">Įmonės kodas</label>';
                $formtxt .='<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" name="company_id" id="company_id" type="text">';      
                $formtxt .='<p>';
                $formtxt .='<label for= "vat_id">PVM mok. kodas</label>';
                $formtxt .='<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" name="vat_id" type="text">';      
                $formtxt .='</div>';
                $formtxt .='</div>';
                $formtxt .='<p>';
                $formtxt .='<input class="button button-xsmall button-line-dark" type="submit" align ="center" name= "cf_submitted" value="Rezervuoti"> <br>'; 
                $formtxt .='<p>';



    $formtxt .='</div>';

    $formtxt .='</form>';
                 $formtxt .= '</div>';
                  return $formtxt;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$formtxt .= '<form  style="width: 800px;" name="time_booking"  action="#" onsubmit="return validateCalendarForm();" method = "POST">';
```

action is set to #. maybe that is the cause. try removing that.

```
action=""
```

additionally a js function `validateCalendarForm()` is calling on form submit. so check console for errors too. and lastly refresh permalink structure